# Request response changes when using proxy (No change in browser)

Tags: python, python-requests

I've been trying to solve a problem for a while now, was hoping some of you guys could help.

I make a request to a website without a proxy, using python-requests. Using the correct headers, everything identical to the browser. I get a successful response, the same as the browser's response.

However when I update the sessions proxies using `session.proxies.update(proxies)`, I get a completely different response. When using this proxy in the browser, it works as normal. I've set up a Wireshark session on both my local computer and the proxy server. The requests are exactly the same for both the local request and the proxy request. No headers are being added from the proxy server.

Is there something I am overlooking which would explain a different response. As said before, I can access the website using the proxy in a browser, even with javascript turned off, so that's not the issue.
Thanks in advance for any help, I really appreciate it

Comment: Are you using private or public/free proxies?

Comment: I've tried with both

Comment: When i worked with public proxies sometimes  I get the html code from Chinese websites. My solution is, when you do a request, execute a function to control "some" element appears in website to know its load correctly. I used xpath to locate elements